# "Illegal string offset" warning for object property array?

Tags: php, arrays, class, warnings

I have this code:

```
class Foo {
    public $bar = array();
}

$foo = new Foo();

$foo -> bar['count'] = 100;
echo $foo -> bar['count']; // 100

$prop = 'bar';
echo $foo -> $prop['count']; // Warning: Illegal string offset 'count'
```

Which gives me this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'count' in ...

Why? And how to make it work?

===================

The reason I want this is:

```
class Foo {
    private $data1 = array();
    private $data2 = array();

    public function loadData1(array $data) {
        return $this -> loadDataInProperty($data, 'data1');
    }

    public function loadData2(array $data) {
        return $this -> loadDataInProperty($data, 'data2');
    }

    private function loadDataInProperty(array $data, $prop) {
        // Filtering, etc.
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            // Keys comparison, etc.
            $this -> $prop[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to load some data into one of the properties (array) of the object. There are quite a few different data sets. Any better / cooler way to achieve this?

Comment: What you expect from that code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $bar = array();
}

$foo = new Foo();

$foo -> bar['count'] = 100;
echo $foo -> bar['count']; // 100
$prop = 'bar';
echo $foo -> {$prop}['count']; // Warning: Illegal string offset 'count'
```

Comment: It works! But why? Is there any official PHP doc on this one?